# Extended TreeView Events Not Firing By Default

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, custom-controls

I've extended the TreeView control to create my own version with a bit more functionality.

In Visual Studio's 'Design View' I can click on a control, view its Events in the 'Properties' panel and double-click next to an Event which throws me into the codebehind and creates an empty Handler for the Event.

The problem I have is that my 'CustomTreeView' control won't actually fire this Handler unless I explicitly state the following in the `'Page_Load'` Event:

```
CustomTreeView1.SelectedNodeChanged += new EventHandler(CustomTreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged);
```

So I can *make* it work, but I'd like to know why I have to do this and how I might be able to get around it by having it happen automatically.

**UPDATE 1**: I've just started from scratch with a new Solution containing a Web Application and Control Library Project, extending a TreeView in the most basic manner possible and testing the Events.  They work as expected with no additional wireup code necessary.  I'm thinking something has gone very wrong with this Solution in general.

**UPDATE 2**: I have a solution - Visual Web Developer Express 2010 is being very hit-and-miss in the way it responds to event handlers being added.  Sometimes, I double-click the event name in the properties panel and even though it creates a handler in my codebehind, it doesn't update the Tag in the aspx page at all.  Other times, it adds the event name in all lowercase to the Tag, which means it gets missed at runtime.  I'll check to see if there's a patch I'm missing.

**UPDATE 3**: VWD is behaving very strangely in more ways now - changes made to an SqlDatasource in the GUI wizard via the smart tag don't get saved to the underlying markup code.  I'm putting this issue down to a broken installation.